# Signalr Hubs Not found (403)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, iis-express, signalr-hub

Right, so I've seen loads of questions about this, but none of the suggested fixes have worked for me.

I have a MVC4 project running in Visual Studio 2012/IIS Express, using SignalR to do some feedback to users. When I run the project I get a 403 error in Chrome like such:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://{website}/Hubs/


Uncaught Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/hubs'></script>.
```

Obviously I've changed the actual domain on my machine to {website}

Now, originally I had it in a folder called signalr in the root of my web project with a subfolder of hubs, but then I read on the SignalR GitHub that you shouldn't do that, so i changed it to just 'Hubs'. Still didnt fix it.

I've also seen the fix regarding putting your RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); in the right order. Mine looks like this:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

I've also seen some people suggesting passing in your route as a parameter into the MapHubs() method, but that takes a string and a HubConfiguration object as a parameter so that's not working either.

My view code looks like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Report", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    <div>
        @(InputExtensions.Hidden(Html, "submittingUserId", ViewBag.CurrentUser))
        @(InputExtensions.Hidden(Html, "signalConnectionId"))
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UploadedFile)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UploadedFile)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="subButton" type="submit" value="UploadFile" title="Upload File" />
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.1.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Hubs")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var accountMovementMoveHub = $.connection.accountMovementHub;
            $("#signalConnectionId").val($.connection.connectionId);

            $.connection.hub.updateProgress = function (message) {
                $("#progress-list").append('<li>' + message + '</li>');

            };

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
    </script>

}
```

I've also added these elements to the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

It's been driving me absolutely insane, I've tried absolutely every suggestion I could find on here, github, and anywhere else for that matter :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

**ANSWER**

So it turns out, I assumed that the script reference to /signalr/hubs was to the PHYSICAL folder containing the hubs. Which it isn't; it is a reference to a virtual directory, which is why if you ALSO have a physical folder called SignalR it gets confused. I moved my hubs folder to my business project, and set the script reference back to "/signalr/hubs" and it all started working.

Sorry about the stupid question and thanks for your answers.

Comment: Looks like you have a trailing slash??? http://{website}/Hubs/

Comment: I think that's just Chrome's console adding that last slash. The error comes from the script reference in the view, which is referencing "~/Hubs"

Comment: Have you viewed the source and confirmed that? Just a thought.

Comment: I have indeed :) source says <script src="/Hubs"></script>

Comment: I think you also get 403 if its a cross domain call for whatever reason or if you have a folder in your project called hubs.

Comment: It's all on the same domain, so that shouldn't be an issue. Why would having a folder named 'hubs' affect it? the same thing happens when I change the folder name and reference to 'tomatoes'.

Comment: I have did this myself. The hubs folder is a route mapping and if you actually have a physical folder called hubs this overrides it.

Comment: Thanks, will try once more and call it something else :)

Comment: Everything here is wrong. Follow the tutorial on asp.net and it'll just work http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); maps your hubs to http://{website}/signalr/hubs

Why are you trying to get the hubs from http://{website}/Hubs?
Simply access both paths from your browsers, you need to get a http response containing a lot of javascript code. If that does not work, then it means your application is not configured right.

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4), you can see the order of RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() is different than what your have

Answer (score 0):

Following the inspiration above I updated my webconfig to look like this:

> script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'

instead of

> script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/hubs") %>' type="text/javascript"

Not sure why, as the folder structure is just ~/Hubs relative to the page, but it works so... ZANG!!!!